# Iterate string lines in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

I get a buffer (and I can make it a string) from `child_process.exec()` in NodeJS. I need to iterate over the lines of the output string. How would I do this?

Comment: is looping over `output.split("\\n")` enough or do you need a non-blocking processing?

Comment: I realize I can just split it, but I was hoping for more performant way to do this as the output can be several megabytes in size.

Comment: @rFactor well you already have the entire buffer in RAM. The only way to make it more performant would be a line reader on a stream

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to avoid splitting the whole thing in memory is to process it one line at a time

```
var i = 0;
while (i < output.length)
{
    var j = output.indexOf("\\n", i);
    if (j == -1) j = output.length;
    .... process output.substr(i, j-i) ....
    i = j+1;
}
```